# How do I Inner join my calendar_table to get full range of calendar dates + my query result from other_table

Tags: mysql

I have a table "calendar_table" with full calendar date set:

```
dt
--------------------------
2014-07-09
2014-07-10
2014-07-11
2014-07-12
2014-07-13
2014-07-14 etc.....
```

I have another table "activity" with columns:

```
aveHR   duration    date
------------------------------
74      91          2014-08-02
59      25          2014-07-31
59      27          2014-07-28
59      27          2014-07-25
59      27          2014-07-22
```

I want to JOIN my calendar_table to get a full sequential range of dates to pad out the missing calendar dates in other_table (first value (2014-07-22) to last value (2014-08-02))

If I run:

```
SELECT aveHR, duration, date FROM `activity`
```

I get:

```
74      91          2014-08-02
59      25          2014-07-31
59      27          2014-07-28
59      27          2014-07-25
59      27          2014-07-22
```

What I am wanting to achieve is the sequential daily dates from: 2014-07-22 to 2014-08-02. I.E. 2014-07-22, 2014-07-23, 2014-07-24, 2014-07-26, 2014-07-27, 2014-07-28, 2014-07-29, 2014-07-30, 2014-07-31, 2014-08-01, 2014-08-02

Where the matching dates from "activity" show their respective data for aveHR and duration and the dates that do not match this show the date only.

```
SELECT aveHR, duration, date, calendar.dt FROM `activity`
INNER JOIN calendar
ON activity.date WHERE date BETWEEN "first and last date from activity.date"
```

This does not work I have no idea how to get the result above any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with `LEFT JOIN`. Something like:

```
SELECT cal.dt, aveHR, duration, date FROM calendar cal
LEFT JOIN `activity` act ON act.date = cal.dt
WHERE dt BETWEEN 
(SELECT MIN(date) FROM activity)
and (SELECT MAX(date) FROM activity);
```

[SQL DEMO FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9c7a3/5)

Comment: OK so: WHERE date BETWEEN first and last date - first and last date columns do not exist they would have to be selected dynamically from the same query

Comment: Ok, I've cmodified the query to get min and max date from `activity` table. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: OK awesome! Seems to work except my activity.date format is: 2014-08-02 11:08:24 and my calendar dt format is: 2014-08-02 - I tried: substr(activity.date,0,10) but it's giving me NULL values for date

Comment: You can get a date from a datetime field with DATE() function. Check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a160e4/6

Comment: Last question: Why did you add act after LEFT JOIN `activity`? and cal after SELECT cal.dt, aveHR, duration, date FROM calendar? Works fine without these, aliases?

Comment: they are just alias, you can remove them (and set act.date as just `date`)